# PDO will not insert to MYSQL DB Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['first-name'];
$lastname = $_POST['last-name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$source = "IP-Demo";

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO Contact (first-name,last-name,Company,email,phone,city,state,zip,country,type,source)
    VALUES (:first-name,:last-name,:Company,:email,:phone,:city,:state,:zip,:country,:type,:source)";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(
    ':first-name'=>$firstname,
    ':last-name'=>$lastname,
    ':Company'=>$company,
    ':email'=>$email,
    ':phone'=>$phone,
    ':city'=>$city,
    ':state'=>$state,
    ':zip'=>$zip,
    ':country'=>$country,
    ':type'=>$type,
    ':source'=>$source
));
```

Comment: Did you check be sure every variables coming from `$_POST` are defined?

Comment: yet another too localized not a real question. Nobody cares. Ever.

Comment: It is a real question, obviously I had a problem and was looking for a solution hence the need to ask a question. Furthermore thanks to Álvaro G. Vicario my code is now functioning properly. Asking the question has served it's purpose in finding a useful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query contains several object names that need backtick quoting, at least these:

- `first-name`
- `last-name`
- `type`

**Edit:** BTW, just tried your code and `prepare()` failed:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '-name,last-name,Company,email,phone,city,state,zip,country,type,source)

Comment: you were correct the hyphens where causing the issue i removed them and everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement assumes `type` as a reserved word instead of column name so it gives 10 columns and 11 params

Try set the ` char in front and in the end of the column name

Answer (score 0):

When using a [real db abstraction](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql) library instead of that inconvenient and limited PDO, all the code will be just few lines. Not to mention it never fails for such a silly reason like forgotten quote.

```
$allowed = explode(',','first-name,last-name,Company,email,phone,city,state,zip,country,type');
$data = $db->filterArray($_POST,$allowed);
$db->query("INSERT INTO Contact SET ?u", $data);
```